# POST a form doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, saml-2.0

I have a `SAML` request for a server which is not a logged in server, so that server takes the request and post it to server which is a logged in server. E.g.

Initially a SAML request is sent to http://customer0.abc.com/HandleServlet which knows that customer1 is the one supposed to handle that request, so in response it submits that request server http://customer1.abc.com/HandleServlet in a POST form. For some reason this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11, but works fine Chrome or Firefox.

```
StringBuffer sbfForm = new StringBuffer();
PrintWriter out = request.getWriter();
request.setContentType("text/html");
sbfForm.append("<html><body onload=\"document.abcform.submit()\">\n");
sbfForm.append("<form action=\"" + destURL + "\"  method=\"POST\" name=\"abcform\">\n");
sbfForm.append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"SAMLRequest\" value=\"" + samlRequestMsg + "\" />\n");
sbfForm.append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"RelayState\" value=\"" + relayState + "\" />\n");
sbfForm.append("</form></body></html>\n");

out.print(sbfForm.toString());
```

This works fine in Chrome or Firefox, but not in IE 11. Has anyone faced similar issue what might be the reason with IE setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with X-Frame-Options and Content Security Policy. Once I changed both, it worked in Internet Explorer and Chrome.